# Is there any way to use autoidle in heroku for free?

Tags: heroku

I want to save my dyno by putting the heroku into idle during night times but it is paid so is there any way to use autoidle in heroku for free?

Answer (score 0):

If your **web** application is on the Free tier then it will automatically sleep after 30 min inactivity (i.e. where there are no HTTP requests).

In the case of a **worker** (background process, it doesn't sleep when deployed standalone) you can use the [Platform API](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference) to manage the Dyno lifecycle